# how to add Date range field in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I want to add date range field in my javascript UI code.please let me know how i can do that.that UI is created by eclipse neon. there is a single date filed for now i want to make it as range

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

```js
$(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>
<div class="date">

<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>

</div><!-- End demo -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery Date Range Picker. For documentation and more demo you can refer here: https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date-range-filter').dateRangePicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    getValue: function() {
      if ( $('#date-from').val() && $('#date-to').val() ) {
        return $('#date-from').val() + ' to ' + $('#date-to').val();
      }
      else {
        return '';
      }
    },
    setValue: function(daterangepicker, from, to) {
      $('#date-from').val(from);
      $('#date-to').val(to);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.20.0/jquery.daterangepicker.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-date-range-picker/0.20.0/daterangepicker.min.css'>
<span id='date-range-filter'>
  From: <input id='date-from'>
  To: <input id='date-to'>
</span>
```